# nvcc -arch sm_52 gives error "Value 'sm_52' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'"

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvcc

I updated my cuda toolkit from 5.5 to 6.5. Then following command

```
nvcc -arch=sm_52
```

starts to give me an error

```
nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_52' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'
```

Is this a bug ? or nvcc 6.5 does not support Maxwell virtual architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CUDA Toolkit 6.5 was released before `sm_52` architecture came into production.

After the arrival of `sm_52` architecture, an update to CUDA 6.5 was released which enabled nvcc to generate code for `sm_52`.

Make sure you download the [newer version of CUDA Toolkit 6.5](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads-geforce-gtx9xx).

**P.S:** I would rather use the [latest version of toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) (currently 7.0).